# How to extract converted value from response using jquery ajax method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, currency-exchange-rates

I am using this link :[freecurrencyconverterapi](https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v4/convert?q=USD_INR&compact=ultra) to get the converted value from USD to INR.

As you can see in developer mode of browser that the response is `{"USD_INR":64.857002}`.
Since I am new to programming, is there a way to get the float value using jquery ajax .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's a different API that works as-is: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/71qt68xt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is returning a JSON object.

You need to assign that response object to a variable in your code, so ultimately it will end up looking like below...

```
var currency = { USD_INR: 64.857002 };
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
currency.USD_INR // This will give you 64.857002
```

See example below..

Edit: As per Rory's code (adapted)...

```js
var currency;

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v4/convert?q=USD_INR&compact=ultra',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
    currency = data.USD_INR;
    console.log(currency);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The question's title is misleading; the main issue here is how to use jQuery's ajax.

Comment: Just change it to JSONP.. Works... please upvote me :-)

Comment: One of the few times that JSONP is supported :) Upvoted you

Comment: Agreed - tbf it was a lucky guess, I nearly didn't bother as I thought it wouldn't work. Thanks Rory

Comment: Thanks @ Rory McCrossan and @ Zinc .This works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, jsonp is supported. Thanks for referencing the site! :)

Answer (score 0):

The url that u provided had an issue, so I took an unorthodox route to get what u wanted;

```js
$.get( "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v4/convert?q=USD_INR&compact=ultra", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).text( data );
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
  console.log(data);
  //alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">
</div>
```